# Animation triggered by buttonClick

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to run an animation in java that is triggered via a button click.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ValueAnimation implements ActionListener
{
    Timer valueClock;
    CodeDrowingPanel codeDrowing;
    TextLineNumber rowHeader;
    private int index;
    private int[] line = {19,21,22,23};

    public ValueAnimation()
    {
        codeDrowing = GUI.externalCodeDrowing;
        rowHeader = GUI.externalRowHeaderCode;
        index = 0;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        valueClock = new Timer();
        valueClock.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                if(index<line.length)
                {
                    rowHeader.gotoStartOfLine(codeDrowing, line[index]);
                    index++;
                }
                else
                {
                    valueClock.cancel();
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
        },0,1000);
    } 
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
valueButton.addActionListener(new ValueAnimation());
```

First time I wasn't seting `index = 0;` after canceling the timer and it was executing the animation just one time no matter how many times I was clicking the button.

I know it is not the most correct way to do it especially with `codeDrowing = GUI.externalCodeDrowing;` and `rowHeader = GUI.externalRowHeaderCode;` but it's working. Any suggestions?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: 1. Use javax.swing.Timer instead of java.util.Timer. 2. Pass the 2 parameters to the ValueAnimation constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the code, this is what i can think of:

```
yourButton.addActionListener(New ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2) {

                if(index<line.length){
                        rowHeader.gotoStartOfLine(codeDrowing, line[index]);
                        index++;
                }else{
                        index = 0;
                }
        }
});
```